# Why does my change not appear in my angular component when changed in parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I started creating my own select component with the following input:

```ts
@Input() options: SelectOption<UserRole>[] = [];
```

The parent (user editor) using this select component gives following options into the component:

```ts
roleOptions: SelectOption<UserRole>[] = [
   { value: 'USER', label: 'User', selected: false },
   { value: 'ADMIN', label: 'Admin', selected: false },
];
```

The parent loads the current user with its user role and sets the role in the constructor:

```ts
// ... get user here ...
this.roleOptions.filter((o) => o.value === user.role).map((o) => (o.selected = true));
```

In the select component I want to adjust the displayed value according to the already assigned user role in the ngOnInit (or whereever). This does not work because the value of 'selected' is always false when filtered for it:

```
this.displayedValue = this.options.filter((o) => o.selected)[0].label;
```

When I print all options, I can see the change but as soon as I try to filter for it, there is no selected role. I tried it with ngOnChanges and the same happens. Can anyone explain why? How can I display the assigned role?

Comment: Angular change detection does not see the change because the input still references the same array. You can assign a copy of the array with new values to the input. Or use a separate input for the selected role and change this new input.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the entire object during the `map` operation!

Before:

```
this.roleOptions.filter((o) => o.value === user.role).map((o) => (o.selected = true));
```

After:

```
this.roleOptions.filter((o) => o.value === user.role).map((o) => {o.selected = true; return o;});
```

The provided code is very minimal, please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging!